Is there a method to fit a vertical hyperbola to a set of points?
I'm trying to fit a vertical hyperbola to scattered points. I'm trying to follow this article "Direct and specific least-square fitting of hyperbolæ and ellipses”
This question is in the context of Ground Penetrating Radar, with the goal of estimating an object's position and radius and the wave velocity in the medium. In short, the wave's trajectory is modelled by a vertical hyperbola, so if this wave can be fitted these parameters may be determined. There are several articles that employ hyperbola fitting to do this but they don't go into much detail.
Considering the vertical hyperbola equation:
$\frac{(y-y_0)^2}{a^2}-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{b^2}=1$
Which can be re-written as:
$-\frac{a^2}{b^2}x^2+1y^2+2\frac{a^2}{b^2}x_0-2y_0y+(y_0^2-a^2-\frac{a^2}{b^2}x_0^2)=0$
This corresponds to the general conic equation, with $b_c=0$, $a_c<$0 and $c_c=1$:
$a_cx^2 + b_cxy + c_cy^2 + d_cx + e_cy + f_c = 0$
$Dz=0, D=[x^2, xy, y^2, x, y , 1], z=[a_c, b_c, c_c, d_c ,e_c ,f_c]^T$
How may I implement a least squares fitting algorithm with these constraints: $b_c=0$, $a_c<0$ and $c_c=1$?

Can you provide a link to the article. Otherwise at least with authors, journal name etc if a link isn’t on hand.

Hi, I've added the link to the article

Here are a couple of approaches. First one is more for simplification and demonstration of how least squares is derived. The second solution makes fewer assumptions and sets up the first of six equations.
There are 4 degrees of freedom in the desired expression. The symmetry of might lend itself to some simplifications. In some cases a simple averaging can give you the degrees of freedom. Then ordinary least squares can give you the other two.
$x_0=<x>=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_n$
$y_0=<y>=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N y_n$
Let $u_i=x_i-x_0, v_i=y_i-y_0, a^2p^2=1, b^2q^2=1$
$q^2v^2-p^2u^2=1\implies q^2<v^2>-p^2<u^2>=1\implies q^2=\frac{1+p^2<u^2>}{<v^2>}$
$v^2=(p^2/q^2)u^2+1/q^2$
$S=\sum(y_i-mx_i-b)^2$
Deriving least squares:
$\partial S/\partial m =  \sum -2x_i(y_i-mx_i-b)=0\implies <xy>=m<x^2>+b<x>$
$\partial S/\partial b = \sum -2(y_i-mx_i-b)\implies <y>=m<x>+b\implies <x><y>=m<x>^2+b<x>$
$m=\frac{<xy>-<x><y>}{<x^2>-<x>^2}$
$b=\frac{<y><x^2>-<x><xy>}{<x^2>-<x>^2}$
This implies $\frac{1}{q^2}=\frac{<v^2><u^4>-<u^2><u^2v^2>}{<u^4>-<u^2>^2}$
and $p^2=\frac{q^2<v^2>-1}{<u^2>}$

Let's see how well this agrees with a more general approach.
$S=\sum (Ax_i^2+By_i^2+Cx_i+D_iy+Ex_iy_i+F)^2=0$
$\partial S/ \partial A = 2x_i^2(Ax_i^2+By_i^2+Cx_i+Dy_i+Ex_iy_i+F)=0\implies A<x^4> + B<x^2><y^2>+C<x^3>+D<x^2y>+E<x^3y>+F<x^2>=0$
You'll have 6 equations in six unknowns allowing you to setup a system of equations.
If you want vertical alignment set $E=0$ and $B<A$. Note this allows you to avoid taking the partial derivative with respect to E.

Follows a MATHEMATICA script which fits a general hyperbola, giving a set of data points. Initially we prepare the point data set, after that a general conic as given by
$$
\mathscr{C}\to a x^2+b x y + c y^2 + d x + e y + f = 0
$$
is fitted using a cumulative error minimization over the furnished data set, including a restriction which guarantees a nontrivial solution: $4 a c - b^2 < 0$
(***** DATA PREPARATION *****)

hyp[p_] := (b p[[2]])^2 - (a p[[1]])^2 - (a b)^2
parms = {a -> 2, b -> 1, x0 -> 2, y0 -> 1};
p0 = {x0, y0};
hyp0 = hyp[p0 + RotationMatrix[Pi/4] . {x, y}] /. parms;
ContourPlot[hyp0 == 0, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}]
n = 50;
X = RandomReal[{-20, 20}, n];
hyp0 = hyp[p0 + RotationMatrix[Pi/4] . {x, y}] /. parms;
tab = Table[Solve[(hyp0 /. {x -> X[[k]]}) == 0, y, Reals], {k, 1, n}];

error = 0.5;
data = {};
For[k = 1, k <= n, k++,
 tabk = tab[[k]];
 If[Length[tabk] > 0, AppendTo[data, {X[[k]] + RandomReal[{-error, error}], (y /. tabk[[1]]) + RandomReal[{-error, error}]}];AppendTo[data, {X[[k]] + RandomReal[{-error, error}], (y /. tabk[[2]]) + RandomReal[{-error, error}]}]]
 ]

(***** FITTING PROCESS *****)

conic[p_] := a p[[1]]^2 + b p[[1]] p[[2]] + c p[[2]]^2 + d p[[1]] + e p[[2]] + f
E2 = Sum[conic[data[[k]]]^2, {k, 1, n}];
sol = Minimize[{E2, 4 a c - b^2 + 1 < 0}, {a, b, c, d, e, f}]

(***** VERIFICATION ******)

gr0 = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.02], Red}];
conic0 = conic[{x, y}] /. sol[[2]]
gr1 = ContourPlot[conic0 == 0, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}];
Show[gr1, gr0]


